# Return string from function (Without Eval)

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, return

I have this function that generates a random string!

```
function randString() {
  var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
      fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
      genHash  = "",
      i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)
    return genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1)
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is when I click a button I want my `genHash` to be various class names.

```
$("[data-action=newlist]").on("click", function() {
  randString()

  var newBtnList = $("<em>", {
    text: genHash,
    title: genHash,
    class: "new-"+ genHash
  }).appendTo("[data-action=list-tree]").on("click", function() {
    // Show active editor
    $("." + genHash).removeClass("hide")
  })
})
```

I know I can do it inside the `randString()` function (such as set it as an input's value and grab the value back from the input), but what I'm trying to figure out is how can I to it outside of the function, thus return the string from the function as states in my title.

```js
function randString() {
  var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
      fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
      genHash  = "",
      i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)
    return genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1)
  }
}

// Create a new list
$("[data-action=newlist]").on("click", function() {
  randString()

  var newBtnList = $("<em>", {
    text: genHash,
    title: genHash,
    class: "new-"+ genHash
  }).appendTo("[data-action=list-tree]").on("click", function() {
    // Show active editor
    $("." + genHash).removeClass("hide")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-action="newlist">
  New
</button>
<div data-action="list-tree"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `randString()` function only returns the first random character due to the `return` statement in the `for` loop. Move it *after* the `for`:

```
function randString() {
    var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
        genHash = "",
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)
        genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1)
    }
    return genHash;
}
```

You can then assign the returned string to a variable in your click event handler:

```
var genHash = randString();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/hcLpzgpn/)

Also note that you can use the `this` keyword in your second click handler to reference the element instead of building a selector from the `genHash` string. Try this:

```
$("[data-action=newlist]").on("click", function() {
    var genHash = randString();

    var newBtnList = $("<em>", {
        text: genHash,
        title: genHash,
        class: "new-" + genHash + ' hide'
    }).appendTo("[data-action=list-tree]").on("click", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hide")
    })
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/hcLpzgpn/1/)

Comment: And the OP is not assigning the return of randString to do anything, `var genHash=randString()`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your function's main cycle to

```
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)
    genHash += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1)
  }
  return genHash;
```

Then change string

```
 randString()
```

in your code to

```
 var genHash=randString()
```

And, yes, in class definition remove "new-". Or replace "."+genHash with ".new-"+genHash

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return the `genHash` variable  value within for `loop` which is incorrect. just return the `genHash` variable value after the loop.

try this one

```
 function randString() {
      var char = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
          fullchar = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
          genHash  = "",
          i;

      for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * char.length)
        genHash  += char.substring(rnum, rnum + 1)
      }
    return genHash ; //change here
    }
```